# How to miss out matrix elements in pcolor plot?

Tags: matlab, plot, conditional-statements

I'm solving a set of nonlinear simultaneous equations using Matlab's [`fsolve`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html) to find unknown parameters `x1` and `x2`. The simultaneous equations have two independent parameters `a` and `b`, as defined in the `root2d` function:

```
function F = root2d(x,a,b)
F(1) = exp(-exp(-(x(1)+x(2)))) - x(2)*(a+x(1)^2);
F(2) = x(1)*cos(x(2)) + x(2)*sin(x(1)) - b;
end
```

I use the following code to solve the simultaneous equations, and plot the results as a 2d figure using [`pcolor`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcolor.html).

```
alist = linspace(0.6,1.2,10);
blist = linspace(0.4,0.8,5);

% results
x1list = zeros(length(blist),length(alist));
x2list = zeros(length(blist),length(alist));

% solver options
options = optimoptions('fsolve','Display','None');

for ii = 1:length(blist)

    b = blist(ii);
    
    for jj = 1:length(alist)
    
        a = alist(jj);
        
        x0 = [0 0]; % init guess
        
        [xopt,yopt,exitflag] = fsolve(@(x0)root2d(x0,a,b),x0,options);
        
        % optimised values
        x1list(ii,jj) = xopt(1);
        x2list(ii,jj) = xopt(2);
        success(ii,jj) = exitflag; % did solver succeed?
        
    end
    
end

% plotting

figure
s = pcolor(alist(success>0),blist(success>0),x1list(success>0));
xlabel('a')
ylabel('b')
title('my data x_1')

figure
s = pcolor(alist(success>0),blist(success>0),x2list(success>0));
xlabel('a')
ylabel('b')
title('my data x_2')
```

However I only want to plot the `x1` and `x2` where the solver has successfully converged to a solution. This is where the `success` matrix element (or `exitflag`) has a value greater than 0. Usually you just write `x1list(success>0)` when using the `plot` function and Matlab omits any solutions where `(success<=0)`, but `pcolor` doesn't have that functionality.

Is there a way around this? For example, displaying all `(success<=0)` solutions as a black area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is!

The easiest way is to make them `NaN`, so they are simply not drawn.

just do

```
x1list(~success)=NaN;
pcolor(alist,blist,x1list)
```